# Home Foundation Warranty Transfer

Tags: first-time-home-buyer, transfer

I recently purchased my first house. The house had some foundation work done a few years ago and the company who did the work supplied a life time warranty. 
This warranty has a Transfer section that describes how to transfer the warranty. The details amount to:

- Send in a basic transfer form
- Provide proof of home ownership
- Give some $$$

A few days after I send everything off, the company contacted me and said that the foundation could be affected by water leakages from the pipes under ground and they are requiring me to get an inspection before they will transfer the warranty. I looked up the recommended inspector and their price is approx. $400! 
I just bought this house, so I'm not quite rolling in the dough.

My question is do I *have* to get this inspection seeings as it is *not* mentioned anywhere in the transfer section of the warranty. The company claimed that it is a policy update since the warranty was issued. I told them I didn't want to pay for it and after much arguing they are sending me a waiver that I must sign before they'll transfer the warranty. Obviously I don't want to sign any waiver. What am I waiving?!

To make all this worse, the transfer has to happen within the first 30 days of when I bought the house. I was within the window until they decided to send the waiver. Now it's a few days past. Can I even still transfer the warranty?

Comment: Where is the house?  What country?  Possibly state, province, etc. as well.  Different jurisdictions have different laws.  Note that there are tags for countries.  You also might consider if this would better fit Law.SE, as this seems more law than finance.  If you sent everything within the first 30 days, in many jurisdictions that will be enough to hold your place and give you more time to fulfill extra requirements not originally disclosed.  But you should talk to a legal professional in your jurisdiction to be sure.  You might check if you've already had an acceptable home inspection.

Comment: Thank you for you input. As per your suggestion, I have moved my question to http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/11427/home-foundation-warranty-transfer